# moving from shared hosting to amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, migration, shared-hosting

I have several websites  - all PHP based (some WP and some native) on a shared hosting service.
It's great - simple control panel (cPanel) for DB and other fast maintenance needs. however, the service's up-time is.. well.. you got the idea.

I want to move it to amazon but it seems like a monster, huge list of options, endless terms which i am not familiar with.

I need a simple "the steps (and terms) are" walk-through and tips.

Note: I'm not asking how to use the system, i will google it myself. i want to understand the concept.

Comment: AWS is an enterprise grade Infrastructure as a Service / Software as a Service platform. People spend hundreds of hours learning to gain qualifications on their platform. You can't get the answer you want by asking this question on SF. Suggest you do some reading to learn what AWS is, and then do some training at Linux Academy or Cloud Guru if you want to learn how to use it. Short hint though: use LightSail, Ubuntu OS, and install a lamp stack. It's still going to be more complex than shared hosting, AWS provides no technical support unless you pay significant money.

Answer (score 2):

General principle: AWS has many services, often overlapping and providing the same function on different levels of abstraction. So you always have to choose and select the 2-3 right ones for your tasks, requirements, and level of control.

Some possible first steps or options to evaluate for your use case:

- use Amazon Lightsail, their new "virtual private server" offering,
- simply use two EC2 instances (for DB and PHP webserver),
- use one EC2 for PHP, and use a managed DB from RDS,
- optionally use AMIs from the marketplace for pre-installed PHP or WP servers,
- optionally add a loadbalancer,
- ...

AWS itself has several introductions and tutorials for this:

- https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-wordpress-website/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/projects/wordpress/

Last but not least, a Google search for "WordPress on AWS" gives plenty of results and blog posts on different approaches.